# Which design pattern to use to process different files in java?

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, rdf

I have simple task to read the information from different files **xml, rdf, txt** with different structure and put it in some **POJO** custom object(MyObject). SO I am wondering which design pattern to use to make my code with better design.

I think on the problem and I think I need *[Factory Patter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)* and the *[Iterator Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/iterator_pattern.htm)*.
On the factory to pass the file:

```
ReaderFactory factory = new ReaderFactory("input.rdf");
//ReaderFactory factory = new ReaderFactory("input.xml");
Iterator<MyObject> iter = factory.getIterator();
```

So the factory base on the file extension to choose which implemnetation of the iterator to return - these which reads rdf,xml or txt. Then with this iterator I easily can process the objects. Add add new files extensions reading in the future.

Comment: or you could use a simple if-then-else to handle the known extensions in order to get the job done: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of how **Factory** and **Strategy** could be used. You create one `AssetManager` (the factory), and register different `AssetLoader`s (the strategies) along with the file extensions they handle. At runtime, your *Factory* selects which *Strategy* to use based on the file extension.

```
public interface AssetLoader
{
    public Object load(String name) throws Exception;
}

public class AssetManager
{
    private HashMap<String, AssetLoader> loaders = new HashMap<>();

    public void addLoader(AssetLoader loader, String extension)
    {
        loaders.put(extension, loader);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T load(String name)
    {
        int i = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i == -1)
            throw new RuntimeException("\"" + name + "\" has no extension, and so has no associated asset loader");

        String extension = name.substring(i+1);
        AssetLoader loader = loaders.get(extension);
        if (loader == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("No loader registered for \"." + extension + "\" files");
        try
        {
            return (T) loader.load(name);
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("\"" + name + "\" could not be loaded as the expected type");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load " + name, e);
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do is create classes that implement the AssetLoader interface for the specific extensions you want to support. Once you have implemented loaders for it, you use it like so:

```
AssetManager assets = new AssetManager();
assets.addLoader(new JsonLoader(), "json");
assets.addLoader(new XmlLoader(), "xml");

Iterator<MyObject> iter = assets.load("input.xml");
```

You could go one step further, and make it a *Singleton*, so you don't have to re-register the different loaders every time you want to load another file.

This approach gives a bit more flexibility to support new file types later on. It does add complexity to your code, but if you plan to add support for multiple file types, it might be worth it.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to think your solution as a design pattern than to think design pattern as your solution.

If you are already considered this, then I think, [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) Pattern might suit your case better.

I am assuming the way you read your input files will remain same regardless of the file format. But you might want to build a POJO depending on the content of the file.

For example:

```
interface FileProcessor {
 public POJO process(BufferedReader br);
}
```

The same interface can be implemented across classes.

```
class RDFFileProcessor implements FileProcessor {
 public POJO process(BufferedReader br) {
  // do your processing logic for rdf file content.
  return POJO;
 }
}
```

Comment: "It is better to think your solution as a design pattern than to think design pattern as your solution." That sounds really profound! However I have _no_ idea what you mean by it. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stop trying to re-invent the wheel. Use [RDF4j](http://rdf4j.org) or [Jena](http://jena.apache.org) which have already solved this problem, at least, for reading RDF.  I recommend RDF4j over Jena, it's much easier to use, but both will work just fine.

Then you can use something like [Pinto](https://github.com/Complexible/pinto) (disclaimer, I'm the author) to map the parsed files into POJOs, similar to Jackson & JSON.

Both RDF4j and Jena have good documentation on their sites on how to use their parsers. I know RDF4j will select the correct parser based on the file extension, which is what you're talking about.

Save yourself some time and energy, use a library to do this for you and actually concentrate on your application.

Comment: This code is for my homework and I have to use two patterns. I do not wat to use custom libraries.